# 500 (URL Rewrite Module Error.) in Angular 7 app on IIS7

Tags: angular, windows, macos, iis, url-rewriting

I have an Angular 7 application I am hosting on IIS 7, which should be accessible at https://example.com/fitcbooks/web. This was working, then suddenly stopped - for reason I can't seem to understand. The URL Rewrite on the server seems to be working (used to redirect other sites on same server) but it just breaks down for this particular app.

I HAVE ALREADY INSTALLED URL REWRITE MODULE 2 for IIS7. I also built the angular application using --base-ref and already used the web.config code as shown below. I have also built a local version of the app and it works perfectly on my macbook running AMPPS, eliminating any issues in the app itself. This looks like a server problem.

web.config:

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Angular Routes" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/fitcbooks/web/index.html" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

index.html:

```
<base href="/fitcbooks/web/">
```

Currently the app's preloader just loads forever. The console shows several 500 (URL Rewrite Module Error.) errors. Please kindly help.

Comment: Use a tool like Fiddler to grab the complete 500 error page, and then see what it says.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @LexLi. I installed Fiddler but didn't really get around to reading the HTTPS 500 details. Eventually used IIS' Failed Request Tracing Rules to setup logs, which I later examined. Your comment helped to point me in that direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally solved this!

The problem was the automatic encryption of files zip-compressed on mac. I just switched from Windows to Mac because of iOS development last week, so I'm new to this.

I was able to figure this out by reading the details of the 500 HTTP error using **Failed Request Tracing Rules** in IIS (thanks to @LexLi for the Fiddler tip). I observed the logs and discovered that the specific Error was **500:50**. Also found `ErrorCode Access is denied. (0x80070005)`, which made me realize it had something to do with access to the file. After some online digging, I found this forum post (https://forums.iis.net/t/1164360.aspx), installed **Process Monitor** and saw that clearly, the Server couldn't access the app's files.

The folders in the app had green labels, so I realized they were encrypted. I re-uploaded the files without encrypting and that was it - the app was working! So I learned the hard way that files compressed on a mac might give you problems on windows.

Just putting this out here in case it helps someone else.

Comment: You'll really love Wireshark too.